# How to use next-auth server side in nextjs 14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, next-auth

Can I use `next-auth` in Next.js 14 app router to get user session and show page responses with SSR? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: https://authjs.dev/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can get user session on the server side:

Install the next-auth package

```
npm install next-auth
```

Create the file `/app/api/auth/[…nextauth]/route.ts`

```js
import { authenticate } from "@/services/authService"
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import type { AuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
      },
      async authorize (credentials, req) {
        if (typeof credentials !== "undefined") {
          const res = await authenticate(credentials.email, credentials.password)
          if (typeof res !== "undefined") {
            return { ...res.user, apiToken: res.token }
          } else {
            return null
          }
        } else {
          return null
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  session: { strategy: "jwt" }
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

Now you can access the session on server side like this:

```js
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server"
import { authOptions } from "@/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route"

export default async function Protected (req: NextRequest): Promise<any> {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)

  return (
    <div className='grid grid-cols-2 text-white p-4'>
      <div>
        {
          session !== null
            ? <h1 className='leading-loose text-[15rem] font-extrabold text-accent'>
                Hi {session?.user.name}!
              </h1>
            : <a className='btn btn-primary' href='/api/auth/signin'>Sign in</a>
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Reference [article](https://medium.com/ascentic-technology/authentication-with-next-js-13-and-next-auth-9c69d55d6bfd) (yes, the articles says Next 13 but the auth will be implemented in same way in Next 14).

Check the docs [here](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example).